# responseXML return null. I'm trying to extract data from an xml file and place it on a site (example from w3schools)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I'm trying to extract data from an XML file and post it on a site (example from w3schools).
The fact is that I work locally, that is, I don’t climb to another domain. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. It may be necessary to specify Http headers. So, as I am new to programming, I don’t deeply know the basics of programming.

I tried to wrap the answer from xml into text.
I ran a browser with advanced features.

```
    //THIS = XML, date = 06.05.2019 (in myFunction come null from 
    //responseXML)

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function loadDoc() {
      xhttp.open("GET", "xmls/"+date+".xml", true);
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
      };
          xhttp.send();
      }




    function myFunction(xml) {
      var i;
      //xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xhttp.responseXML, 'text/xml');
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      console.log(xml);
      var table="<tr><th>name</th><th>value</th></tr>"; 
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Valute");

      for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
          "</td><td>" +
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
          "</td></tr>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
      }
```

I expect responseXML will not be Null

Comment: Please add XML sample format

Comment: <?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Valute>
<Name>USD</Name>
<Value>1.7</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute>
<Name>EURO</Name>
<Value>1.9026</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute>
<Name>Australia</Name>
<Value>1.1884</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute>
<Name>Argentina</Name>
<Value>0.0382</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute>
<Name>Belorus</Name>
<Value>0.8046</Value>
</Valute>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Ok, so it's not the request. It's the XMl that is invalid.

Default XML files can only have one root element, where your XML sample contains multiple `<Valute>` tags after each other and no schema to validate that. So if you wrap those `<Valute>`'s inside a separate root tag, everything works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Valutes>
    <Valute>
        <Name>USD</Name>
        <Value>1.7</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute>
        <Name>EURO</Name>
        <Value>1.9026</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute>
        <Name>Australia</Name>
        <Value>1.1884</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute>
        <Name>Argentina</Name>
        <Value>0.0382</Value>
    </Valute>
    <Valute>
        <Name>Belorus</Name>
        <Value>0.8046</Value>
    </Valute>
</Valutes>
```

Then the request will parse the `.xml` file into an XML document without any changes to the rest of the code. So when I console.log() `xhttp.responseXML`, I get `[object XMLDocument]` and its contents.

I used the following code to test, with the xmltest.xml file containing the XML above.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open( 'GET', 'http://www.someserver.com/resources/xmltest.xml', true );
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert( 'got response' );
        console.log( xhttp.responseXML );
    }
};
xhttp.send();
```

PS: The MIME types still have to be correct on both the client and the server. But XML should be supported natively.

PPS: My PS in the previous answer is still valid. I get better results by parsing the XML to JSON on the server and not bothering with XML on the client.

Comment: i did as you said and the following came out.
1.

The provided value 'text/xml' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.
2.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at myFunction ((index):50)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: i did as you said and the following came out.
Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null.
Xml return null again .

Comment: @RamilAskerov I have updated my answer. Try fixing the XML file first. Then everything works for me in the mockup I made.